# Elasticsearch Java API - fuzzy search with max_expansion

Tags: java, api, elasticsearch

How can I translate the ["more complex" fuzzy example](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/fuzzy-query.html) from the QueryDSL guide into Java?

What I have so far is this: (Which works fine, but for example I'm unable to find the builder methods for "max_expansion", which would allow me to restrict the query)

```
QueryBuilders.fuzzyQuery("name", "kimchy")
```

Any pointers into the right direction are appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It supposed to be `QueryBuilders.fuzzyQuery("name", "kimchy").maxExpansion(5)`. But, unfortunately, the maxExpansion() method is currently missing. So, until [this pull request](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/pull/1882) is merged, the only way to send this query is by expressing it directly in json. You can do it using XContentBuilder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the fix, that's what I was thinking too

Answer (score 1):

Construct a [Lucene FuzzyQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/FuzzyQuery.html) directly, then you can pass that option into a constructor arg.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did end up using the built-in XContentBuilder.